# Initialize elements with brackets like Lists in c#

Tags: c#, collection-initializer

I was thinking about arrays and lists and wondering if and how classes can get an implementation to be initializable like them. Let's take this class as basis:

```
class TestClass
{
    private List<int> Numbers = new List<int> ();

    // Insert code here
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is to take the given values and internally fill my list.

```
TestClass test = new TestClass () { 2, 4, 7, 10 };
```

What would be normally possible is this:

```
List<int> test = new List<int> () { 2, 4, 7, 10 };
```

But I would like to have it for my own custom classes. The next question, which is optional, is if the same can be done for this syntax:

```
TestClass test = { 2, 4, 7, 10 };
```

I assume that is less likely to be possible. Note, these are different from this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat() { Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 };
```

These are direct and optional declarations of internal fields and properties.

[See also MSDN for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Comment: You could inherit from `List<int>` instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers), collection initialisers will work on any class that implements `IEnumerable` *and* has an `Add()` method.

```
class TestClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private List<int> Numbers = new List<int> ();

    public void Add(int n)
    {
        Numbers.Add(n);
    }

    // implement IEnumerable methods down here ...

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() => Numbers.GetEnumerator();

    // etc ...
}
```

Note that if you have more than one parameter in your `Add()` method signature, then you can enclose them in curly braces to use collection initialiser syntax.

```
class TestClass2 : IEnumerable<(int, int)>
{
    private List<int> Numbers = new List<(int, int)> ();

    public void Add(int x, int y)
    {
        Numbers.Add((x, y));
    }

    // implement IEnumerable methods down here ...

    public IEnumerator<(int, int)> GetEnumerator() => Numbers.GetEnumerator();

    // etc ...
}
```

Would be used like this:

```
var test = new TestClass2 { {2, 3}, {4, 5} };
```

Answer (score 8):

You just need an `Add` method to make this work and implement the `IEnumerable` interface:

```
class TestClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private List<int> Numbers = new List<int> ();

    public void Add(int n)
    {
        Numbers.Add(n);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Numbers.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The compiler will recognize the collection initializer syntax and will try to find a matching `Add` method.

Comment: Looks like you have to implement `IEnumerable` as well.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Yes, of course. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: It does not have to be generic, by the way :)

Comment: No, it is better that way since you know the type after all. In that way you help LINQ too. Else you would need to `Cast<int>()` first. @PavelTupitsyn

Answer (score 4):

Technically, the *minimum* requirements are

1. `IEnumerable` interface (of course, `IEnumerable<T>` is a better choice)
2. `Add` method

Minimum example (demonstration only):

```
  class TestClass: System.Collections.IEnumerable {
    public void Add(int value) { }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
      // Just to demonstrate, do not do this in production code
      return null;
    }
  }

  ...

  TestClass myTest = new TestClass() {1, 2, 3};
```

In your case:

```
  class TestClass: IEnumerable<int> {
    private List<int> Numbers = new List<int>();

    // This is required
    public void Add(int value) {
      Numbers.Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
      return Numbers.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // This is required
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @laptou: yes, I totally agree with you that returning `null` is a *nasty* code; as well as implementing `System.Collections.IEnumerable` without `IEnumerable<T>`. I've olny tried to show the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second subquestion: if it is possible to do

```
TestClass test = { 2, 4, 5, 7 };
```

I don't think this is correct syntax anywhere. However you could create something that looks like it using the implicit operator.

Since you can instantiate an `int array` like this: `new[] {1,2,3,4}`, you can create the following in your `TestClass`.

```
public class TestClass {
   private IEnumerable<int> list;
   public TestClass(IEnumerable<int> _list) {
       this.list = _list;
   }

   public static implicit operator(int[] input) {
        return new TestClass(input.ToList());      
   }
}
```

Then create a new TestClass like this;
`TestClass testClass = new[] {1,2,3};`

Comment: This is pretty funky though and probably not a good idea in general. Better to just use the constructor. It only saves you a couple of braces and keywords, which is really not worth much.

Comment: Sure, but still nice to know about it, even if it comes with the advice not to use it.